# Get posts by multiple ID's (query)

Tags: posts, query

I try to get multiple post by ID.
For this I created an array for **p** but I get only the post for the first ID.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'p'                      => array('206', '189'),
    'post_type'              => array( 'product' ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at the [documentation for WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)?

The `p` parameter takes only a single integer.

Use `post__in`.

```
$args = array(
    'post__in'    => array( 206, 189 ),
    'post_type'   => 'product',
);
```